# Free Windows Virtual Machine Images?

Tags: windows, virtual-machine

I came across this tool called [vagrant up](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/getting-started/boxes.html) and in the documentation it points to a list of [freely available virtual machine images](https://atlas.hashicorp.com/boxes/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&sort=&provider=&q=windows) which includes windows. Does that mean that we can run windows for free? It seemed too good to be true to me and that's why I'm asking. Is it a stripped down version of windows that they provide?

Comment: The images may be free, the licenses aren't.

Answer (score 3):

No, Windows is not free.

Just read the descriptions of of the VMs on the link you provided says they are Windows Server trial/test versions.  They will only work for a short amount of time.

MS does offer VMs of various Windows OSs for testing as well, but they run only for a limited time.

Answer (score 3):

No. There is no free Windows. They may provide images but you must provide licenses.

As for licensing options it gets complicated with Microsoft, so I suggest you call them and ask about your options.

I also suggest you create your own image if you purchase licenses as you can never know what kind of installation media they used, and it's most likely out of date.